# Is the Gamma function superadditive?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

A function $f$ is superadditive if $f(x) + f(y) \le f(x+y)$. The question is:

Does a real number $a$ exists such that for all 
real numbers with $x, y\ \ge \ a $

$$ \Gamma(x) + \Gamma(y) \le \Gamma(x+y) \quad ?$$

Comment: Nice question. So, with whuber's solution, a=2 suffices to prove that it is. Now, what's the smallest a so Γ is superaddictive?

Comment: It cannot go below $a=1.4324$ the solution of $2\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(2x)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$a = 2$ will do, because (letting $x \ge y$ wlg),

$\Gamma(x+y) \ge \Gamma(x+2) = (x+1)x \Gamma(x) \ge 6 \Gamma(x) \ge \Gamma(x) + \Gamma(x) \ge \Gamma(x) + \Gamma(y)$.